# When using threads to calculate pi I seam to get a random number

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, math

When I run the code:
`

```
from decimal import *
import threading
from threading import Thread as thr
getcontext().prec = 600

n = 1
num = 0
io = []


def ev(oldNum, startingVal, rangeValue, countThread):
    global io
    number = oldNum
    for x in range(rangeValue):
        number += Decimal(1/(startingVal+(countThread*x)))
    io.append(number)

thread_count = 2 * 8 #the 8 is the amount of threads but it works better on 4

def listThread():
    return [thr(target=ev,args=(0,x,10000,thread_count)) for x in [y for y in range(thread_count) if y%2 == 1]]

rt = listThread()
for x in rt:x.start()
for x in rt:x.join()

k = 0
for x in range(len(io)):
    if x%2 == 1: k += io[x]
    else: k-= io[x]

print(k*4)
```

`
it outputs some what random numbers but its close to pi some times but other wise some what random.

Well I expect like a 3.141.... number, but what happens is I get numbers like:
-4.2831871070152418163795909116
-3.3012509847329211406472558276
-4.7553025041924179591482330532
1.8065589523420867228449138284

Comment: What can you say about the order that results will be appended to the `io` list? (Hint: not much.) But in the final loop, you're assigning meaning to that order, by treating items at even position in one way and those at odd position in another.